# Nagios NSCA - Status Information "OK"

Tags: nagios, ncsa

Thanks for taking the time to read this post.

Basically I have Nagios receiving status updates from workstations in my LAN, I have a simple .vbs script run on the workstation which gets the file version number from certain .exe's then send that to Nagios so I can see the file version within Nagios of Software like Skype,Firefox,Thunderbird,Java,Adobe.

They are static as they are always set to green but that Is not the problem.

If i check the status update it says "OK" but if I check the status updates in a terminal window using tail -f on /var/log/messages I can see the program version number fine. So why is the web interface only showing "OK"

When using NSCE and the same scripts I have no issue, so it has to be something do with NSCA.

Any ideas? I have provided some images to make it easier.

[image: The top host is using NSCE the bottom is using NSCA]

[image: This is from a terminal window]

Again thanks for reading this post, thanks for any help.

Sam

Comment: Can we see the content of a file that NCSA is submitting?  Is that what you are showing above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Nagios/NSCA will stop parsing the returned text at the first carriage return and/or line feed in the text.  So having multiply lines in the output usually doesn't work without some hacks.

Second, the CGI will also not show this information (on that view anyway) if it is sent as performance data (after a pipe '|' character) in the returned text.

Third, in that CGI view, there is a limit to the number of characters that will be show in that box.  You may have to click the link to see the LONGSERVICEOUTPUT and SERVICEPERFDATA, depending on which place your trying to insert these lines in?

Finally, NSCA (again, unless hacked) will cut off any text greater than 1023 characters.

You should edit your vbs script so that it returns the data as one single line and be sure that no pipe characters are placed before it.  Remember, you are quite limited to how much you can 'output'.  And you could always hack NSCA, mine supports 16K of returned text.